# Automatically update apps inside the Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

Recently I have a question. If I write an UWP app and install into a Raspberry Pi with Windows IoT Core OS, is it possible that I set a automatic OTA update for my app inside the Raspberry Pi, just like normal UWP apps in Windows App Store do?

EDIT: Just for my apps, not for upgrading Windows OS (since it can be upgraded directly by Windows Update)

Answer (score 2):

Great question.

I'd suggest looking at a higher level device management solution that can provide updates of any type to a device via an IoT event hub. This is still in preview but check out this Microsoft post on getting started with something like this:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/iot-hub-device-management-get-started/

Comment: Excellent! I will have a try later!

Comment: link died :/ Is there an alternative for this,.?

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows IoT Core does not contain the Windows Store, it is impossible to enable automatic app updates like on your Windows 10 PC with the built-in tools. As far as I know you can only manually upload an app from your Pi's web interface, Visual Studio or maybe CMD/PowerShell/putty.

Comment: Okay thanks. Then... is it possible to run a background .NET console executable program (commmon *.exe binary) to do this kind of job?

Comment: ...or probably some powershell script?

Comment: No, you cannot run background .NET console executable, you'll run into some .NET framework assembly missing exception. .NET framework does not support ARM.

Comment: You'll need to target .NET Core.

Comment: @Jackie Okay thanks for your reply. I will have a try on .NET Core instead, or probably use pure c/c++

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can use ProcessLauncher function in UWP app and start a new exe binary (of course it has to be compiled for ARM platform) to do the job. See here: [Windows Developer - ProcessLauncher](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/samples/ProcessLauncherSample.htm).

But anyway, my RPi3 is still on the way right now, I can't prove if my app can really can let another exe binary (or PowerShell script) to upgrade itself. Hope it can~!