# Windows 10 IoT Core Manage App Updates for Multiple Devices

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm running Windows 10 IT Core on a few Raspberry Pi 3 devices. For these devices, I have developed an application, which reads some sensor data and posts them to a web service. Now when I have to make changes to this app, I have to update it on all these devices.

Do I need to put the app in the Microsoft store for this task, or are there other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to [update applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/service/iot/updating-iot-core-apps) on your IoT device with Windows IoT Core.

- **Using Microsoft Store**: The app is published and updated from the Microsoft Store.Please note that the Microsoft Store Client is not supported in Windows 10 IoT Core,so it can not update app by using Microsoft Store Client like on Windows Desktop.In this option, the apps that is pre-packaged needs to be Microsoft Store compliant apps (store signed), and need to put to store.
- **Using Component Update Service**: The app is published to Windows Update and updated like any other OEM package (driver package).But it is in schedule and coming soon.
- **Using Azure IoT Device Management**: The app is published to Azure Storage and updated through the Azure DM channel New for Windows 10, version 1709.
- **Using OMA-DM**: The app is updated using an OMA-DM compliant device management channel such as Intune or System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM).

Comment: Thank you Michael. So when I publish a new update from an App to the Microsoft Store, the IoT device will update it automatically, or do I have to configure something?

Comment: Please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/iot-core/commercialize-your-device/InstallingAndServicing).And you need to create a service on IoT device throught following [Download and install package updates for your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates).You can get some good information from this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552068/automatically-update-apps-inside-the-windows-10-iot-core).

Comment: Ok. The Azure IoT device management also seems to be a good way, is it correct, that this way I don't need to publish the app package to the Store?

Comment: Yes,the app package is published to Azure Storage.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I will take a look at these options.